# Compare pointer with offset to a value

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, intel

Address `00B6F5F0` contains the address of a pointer (`0429C3B0` which is dynamic and will change on next program startup and that is why I need to use static `00B6F5F0` instead). I need to compare that pointer plus a `530` offset to value `0` which is a 4 byte int.

Pseudo code:

```
00B6F5F0 -> 0429C3B0 (dynamic address will change next time)
0429C3B0 + 530 = 0429C8E0
Is 0429C8E0 equal to 0?
```

The following assembly simply adds the offset to `00B6F5F0`, which is not what I want. How can I add the offset to the pointer `0429C3B0`?

```
cmp [00B6F5F0+00000530],0 <--- (incorrect!)
```

Comment: Load it into a register first. `mov eax, [00B6F5F0]; cmp dword [eax+00000530],0`.

Comment: It sounds like you left out a step in your description:  you don't want to compare the pointer, you want to compare the value it points to.  That's why you need two instructions to do two loads, because you have the extra level of indirection from the pointer being stored in memory, rather than being a compile-time (or link-time) constant like a static array would be.

Comment: @Jester: How about posting that as an answer?